# Are most physics books wrong about the covariant derivative and connection?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I have always read in many physics books that a valid way of intuitively introducing the covariant derivative and the connection was the following: (example in GR but same thing for gauge theories)

Let $TM$ be the tangent bundle over a manifold $M$. I define the "weird" derivative $\partial^{\mathfrak w}$ of a vector $V$ (only the element of the tangent space obtained by projecting to the second element) at $\gamma(t_o)$ as $$\partial^{\mathfrak w}_WV=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{V_{\gamma(t_o+h)}-V_{\gamma(t_o)}}{h}$$ where $W_{\gamma(t_o)}=\dot\gamma(t_o)$ .

This derivative breaks the properties of a vector, because if the limit is to be intended as "limit of components" then transition function (jacobian) loses its meaning, whereas if intended as subtraction of differential operators, independent of coordinates, then it does not make sense because they do not take functions over the same point in $M$.

But all of this because I am exceeding out of the fiber.

In general here you read in these books that you cannot sum different vectors because they are belonging to different tangent spaces (fibers), so you introduce a covariant differentiation. But we know that the tangent space is a vector bundle and thus it admits a local trivialization, therefore the fibers are locally isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, so the two spaces are indeed isomorphic.

$\textbf{Question}$: I would say that I can define such a weird derivative in the sense of components in $\mathbb R^n$, I would simply go out of the fiber and thus I can no longer talk about vectors and change of charts. What do you think?
(Btw, in components this derivative would be the ordinary derivative $\partial_\mu$ that we find in the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu V^\nu=\partial_\mu V^\nu+\Gamma_{\mu\alpha}^\nu V^\alpha$ .)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, what's written in books is right and readers are wrong.

Comment: False of course, even though mine was clickbait 100%. In any case, as a rule of thumb, if you want to give a contribution, try to give a contribution.

Comment: You can make sense of this if your manifold is embedded in R^n. You identify the tangent spaces of the ambient euclidean space and compute this derivative, then project the result onto the tangent space of your manifold. Thorpe's book on elementary differential geometry has the details on this.

Comment: Can you give examples of such books.

Comment: Dirac's book on GR follows the method described by Lorenzo

Comment: @Mtec: as a rule of thumb, arrogance is not welcome.

Comment: You were the arrogant here, I am sorry. If you really wanted to give a contribution you should have said where I was wrong and stuff, not pointed out that my question may have been kind of silly without saying anything to improve the conversation.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo and Spencer ! I wasn't wondering about embedded manifolds. But I understood what you said. Tomorrow I will explain myself better and reformulate the question here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think OP was arrogant here, physics books are frequently "wrong" about mathematics. Wrong in the sense that they eschew rigour and proper definitions for intuition and heuristics, which is often fine for physics, but it is still "wrong" in the absolute sense.

Comment: @BenceRacskó that's absolutely what I meant. I have found errors many times. Physicists tend to be sloppy. (Fortunately there are also careful authors).